# PHP HTTP 500 trying to make GET request from an api

Tags: php, api, get, request, blockchain

I'm trying to do A GET request to an API but it gives me a 500 Http error.

I tried the same thing on https://reqbin.com/ and it worked without any error

What's the problem in my code?

My code:

```
$addr = $_GET['addr'];
$api_key = 'secure';
$url = 'https://www.blockonomics.co/api/merchant_order/'.$addr;
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Authorization: Bearer $api_key",
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$contents = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$object = json_decode($contents);
```

Comment: I would not recommend using `file_get_contents` to get data from a URL. URL access is usually blocked on most servers. Instead, look into [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php), which is more robust.

Comment: @aynber already tried but it gives me same error

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: @aynber so my code is fine right?

Comment: There are no obvious errors, but that doesn't mean that there are no errors. Check the server error log for more information.

Comment: Are you talking about a 500 response from the remote API here, or from your own script?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to catch any error messages:

```
<?php
$addr = $_GET['addr'];;
$api_key = 'your_api_key';
$url = 'https://www.blockonomics.co/api/merchant_order/'.$addr;
$options = array (
    'http' => array (
    'header' => "Authorization: Bearer $api_key",
    'ignore_errors' => true
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$contents = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$object = json_decode($contents);

if($object->status != 200) {
  echo $http_response_header[0]."\n".$contents;
}
```

This way you will see the error message which tells you what is wrong:

> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
>
> {"status": 500, "message": "Order not found."}